# How to access ajax request parameter in thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, ajax, thymeleaf

I have this Ajax call that works fine. The controller receives the call and does what it supposed to do.

The controller method (here I am intentionally throwing exception to test error message that i need to display)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteContentFromMarineCustomer", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = "application/json")
public HttpEntity<String> deleteContentFromMarineCustomer(@RequestParam(value = "srcId") String srcId, @RequestParam(value = "customerId") String customerId, @RequestParam(value = "locale") String locale, @RequestParam(value = "method") String method) {
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
    try {
        // oneChartService.deleteContentFromMarineCustomer(customerId, srcId);
        // responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        throw new Exception("test");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>("Delete", HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
    }

    return responseEntity;

}
```

Now my js looks like this

```
function deleteSelectedContent() {
var link = "content/deleteContentFromMarineCustomer?srcId=" + srcId + "&customerId=" + customerId + "&locale=" + locale+"&method=Delete";
jQuery.ajax({
    url : link,
    type : 'DELETE',
    success : function(data, status) {
        window.location.reload();  
    },
    error : function(data, status) {
        jQuery("#errorContentModal").show();
    }
});
```

Now my problem is when displaying the page I want to pass the method name to it so that it can display the proper message

my html

```
    <div id="errorContentModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog-content" align="center">
     <h3 th:text="#{serviceContentError(${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('method')})}"></h3> 
    <!--<h3 th:text="#{serviceContentError('Delete')}"></h3>-->
    <button class="close" th:text="#{button.ok}"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically the commented out line has the hard coded text which i want to read from the request so that i can make this code generic for other methods to use.

Issue is #httpServletRequest.getParameter('method') returning null. My original call to the page had locale=en_US so when I do this #httpServletRequest.getParameter('locale') this works fine. Since this is an Ajax call for some reason it’s not understanding it.

Does anyone know why i can't read the Ajax request call with this code?

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following and let me know if this worked for you.

the data object in error callback will have the return message, so why not set the error message there.

```
error : function(data, status) {
      //test if data object return the correct value
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.delete);
      $("#test").val(data.delete);
      jQuery("#errorContentModal").show();
}
```

and declare the id (test3) in the html

```
<h3 id="test"></h3>
```